# how not to open all files in a folder in Notepad++

Tags: file, notepad++

Trying to filter file types in Notepad++ Open file dialog box opens all files of that type in that folder

I tried to go through the Options but given they are so many, can't seem to figure out whether one can get Notepad++ to just show the files of that type instead of opening them all

I don't have any code for this

Expected results: show all files of a file type
Actual result: all files are opened.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The *Open File* only displays files in a folder. You set the types of files to display using the *Files of type* list at the bottom, but that does not open even a single file, much less all of them. The dialog does not *open them all* unless you select them all before clicking the *Open* button. I've used NP++ for several years and have never once had it *open all files in a folder* when using the *Open File* dialog without my specifically choosing for it to do so.

Comment: In the past, I used to type '**.abc' in the filename section and pressed 'Enter' and it would filter the listed files to that type and display.  Then I could select the pertinent files and open them.  Now, if type in "*.abc" for the filename, it seems to open all files of that type.

Comment: If I type `.txt` in the filename edit and hit enter, I get a prompt that says *File .txt does not exist. Create it?*. It has always worked that way, at least on Windows. It certainly does not open all .txt files in the folder (and there are about a dozen in the folder I used for testing). If you type `*.txt` and hit enter, you're specifically telling it to open all text files in the folder, and it's going to do exactly what you asked and open them all. Use the drop down list to select file types to display.

Comment: What you described works for me. I typed `*.xml` in the file name input, and it filtered to those files. (and any folders already present) I'll have to see if there's any setting. I have version 7.7.

Comment: Yes, Paul's setting change worked for me.  Thanks very very much!

Answer (score 2):

I found the setting: (I had never changed this setting, so it was curious)

[image]